# Сайт на wordpress - get_option() всегда возвращает false

Tags: wordpress

У меня возникла такая проблема. Сайт на wordpress, любой вызов get_option() из файлов темы возвращает false. Причем сам метод отрабатывает. В итоге сайт не работает. Пока что временно закоментировал проверку в header.php

```
<?php 
    wp_head(); 
    $themename = wp_get_theme();
    $themename = preg_replace("/\W/", "_", strtolower($themename) );
    //if( !get_option( $themename ) ) {
    //require get_template_directory() . '/index-default.php';
    //exit;
    //}
?>
```

Если передавать параметр, то срабатывает. Например

```
get_option('template');
```

Возвращает название темы.

Comment: [`get_option`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_option) возвращает `false`, когда параметра нет в базе. Если нужен нестандартный параметр, то его надо [добавить в базу](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_option) прежде, чем использовать. Где вы задаёте параметр с именем, которое оказывается в `$themename`?

Answer (score 0):

1. wp_get_theme() - Возвращает:
   Экземпляр объекта WP_Theme, который содержит следующие данные:

Name - название темы указанное в style.css;

ThemeURI - УРЛ страницы шаблона;

Description - описание темы;

Author - автор темы;

AuthorURI - УРЛ автора темы;

Version - текущая версия;

Template - (произвольно используется в дочерних темах) название папки родительской темы;

Status - опубликована ли тема;

Tags - метки используемые для описания темы;

TextDomain - название, используемое при локализации темы;

DomainPath - путь до файлов перевода темы;

Далее, смотрите, какую опцию Вы проверяете и что проверяете.